# Set variable from content of files in bash(loop)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I'm trying to upload certificates(just created) to some storage.

So I can read all certificates in my folder and want to use content of each of this file to a variable in a loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="${0%/*}"
#for f in $(cat $dir"/"*.crt)
#  do
#    data='{"certificate_data":'"$f"'}'
#done 
url="localhost:50183/api/v0.1/Certificates"
data='{"certificate_data":'$(cat $dir"/"*.crt)'}'
echo "$data"
```

So I got all certificates in one time but I need to get in $data each of content of files in a loop with correct form something like:

```
{"certificate_data":"<certificate_data_from_file>"}
{"certificate_data":"<certificate_data_from_file>"}
......
and so on
```

I know that I should use another one loop but don't know how.

Be grateful for any tips!

Comment: Side note: `$(cat file.txt)` can be replaced with `$(< file.txt)`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing with the information since your simple example keeps overwriting `data`. But perhaps within your same `for` loop you would have `data_file='{"certificate_data":'"$f"'}'` then `data_cert='{"certificate_data":'$(< $dir"/"*.crt)'}'` followed by whatever logic you want to do with `$data_file` and `$data_cert`.

Comment: ok, just try to delete `for f in $(cat $dir"/"*.crt)
  do
     data='{"certificate_data":'"$f"'}'
done` and it's work without it, but filled all certificates in 1 "certificate_data" and I need to put 1 certificate to 1 "certificate_data"

Comment: Does it help when you change both data assignments? `data="${data}{\"certificate_data\":....}" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ./dir/*.crt
do
  data='{"certificate_data":"'"$(< "${f}")"'"}'
  echo "${data}"
done
```

Test:

```
$ ls ./dir/*
./dir/cert1.crt  ./dir/cert2.crt
$ cat ./dir/*
I am certificate1.
I am certificate2.
$ ./cert.sh
{"certificate_data":"I am certificate1."}
{"certificate_data":"I am certificate2."}
```

Comment: No need per se to pollute memory with a variable. Just put the magic sauce directly in the `echo` argument.

Comment: I think that questioner wants to have it in variable, so he can do something? with it. echo here is only test of doing something with variable.

Comment: Thanks, it should be work, but not for me. I try to set current directory `cwd=$(pwd)` then `for f in $cwd"/"*.crt` and get only 1 certificate data. I need to separate *.crt files from other files because my 1st script generate different types of certificates and keys for them, so I need paste only certificate data without data from *.key files.

Comment: I edited anser to take only .crt, if You wanna all crts in current dir, use following: for f in "$(pwd)/"*.crt                 anyway for safer solution I would use rather find -exec or xargs -0 combo

Comment: Can I ask why when I used echo "${data}" after loop it shows me only 2nd (of 2) certificates. But when use it in loop it shows me 2 of 2?

Comment: After loop ends variable holds only the last content of last crt file. In loop we loop through all files. Do not know if that helped.